# QRegExp: No such file or direcory

Tags: c++, regex, qt

I dont understand why Im getting the following error:

> C:\Users\jacqu\Desktop\SMG-DS\SMG-DS\orderform.cpp:8: error: QRegExp: No such file or directory
> ..\SMG-DS\orderform.cpp:8:10: fatal error: QRegExp: No such file or directory
> 8 | #include "QRegExp"
> |          ^~~~~~~~~

I keep getting this even though i include RegExp as follows:
`#include <QRegExp>`
or as `#include "QRegExp"`

this is the code where i use it:

```
bool orderform::nv(QString num) //Validates phone numbers
{
    QRegExp nv("^\\+?(1 |)[0-9]{3}\\-[0-9]{3}\\-[0-9]{4}$");
    nv.setPatternSyntax(QRegExp::RegExp);
    bool regMat = nv.exactMatch(num);
    if(regMat == false)
    {
    QMessageBox *message = new QMessageBox(this);
    message->setWindowModality(Qt::NonModal);
    message->setText("Please insert a valid phone number");
    message->setStandardButtons(QMessageBox::Ok);
    message->setWindowTitle("ERROR");
    message->setIcon(QMessageBox::Information);
    message->exec();
    ui->edtCustPhone->setFocus();
    ui->edtCustPhone->selectAll();
    return false;
    }else{
    return true;
    }
};
```

Comment: You include this file by doing `#include <QRegExp>`, but are you sure that your editor scans all the libraries in their respective paths, and that you supplied them properly to the compiler. This sounds as if the QT installation wasn't found properly. Additionally, you can try cleaning your project and try compiling it again.

Comment: Which version of Qt are you using?  In Qt6 [`QRegex`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qregexp.html) is part of the `core5compat` package and may not be installed by default.

Comment: Im on QT6, i will try to install that package now thanks

Comment: @G.M. sorry for the stupid question but how do i add it? im still really new to QT and development as a whole...

Comment: The Qt documentation tells you how to do so for CMake or QMake here: [https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtcore5-index.html](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtcore5-index.html)

Comment: You may want to consider using `QRegularExpression` instead: https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qregularexpression.html

Answer (score 10):

I think you are using latest version of QT.like 6.2.2
QRegExp is removed from latest version so that's why QT is not able to find the file.

we have to use  QRegularExpression in latest version instead of QRegExp.

```
  ex. Mobile number format +915525663366

     QRegularExpression rx("[+][1-9]\\d{0,12}");
     QValidator *l_validator = new QRegularExpressionValidator(rx, this);
     ui->mobileNoLineEdit_2->setValidator(l_validator);

  ex.Mobile number format 5525663366
     QRegularExpression rxnum("[1-9]\\d{0,12}");
     QValidator *l_valid = new QRegularExpressionValidator(rxnum, this);
     ui->mobileNoLineEdit_2->setValidator(l_valid);
```